# cannot create an object in database using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to connect hibernate with my db and insert an object in the table.
But it is showing org.hibernate.MappingException error followed by a series of error as shown in images.I will be thankful, if anyone can help.
Here are my code snippets:
App.java

```
    package com.mihir.hibDemo;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

    public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) 
    {
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setId(6);
        p1.setName("Nimisha");
        
        Configuration con = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Person.class);
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder sr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(con.getProperties());
        SessionFactory sf = con.buildSessionFactory(sr.build());
        Session s = sf.openSession();
        Transaction ts = s.beginTransaction();
        s.save(p1);
        ts.commit();
    }
}
```

Person.java

package com.mihir.hibDemo;

```
public class Person {
        private int id;
        private String name;
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">0924</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/college</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="com.mihir.hibDemo.Person"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

[image: errors]

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using? From the xml config I'm assuming an older version. Does this version require *.hbm.xml mapping files for your Entities?

Comment: hibernate 6.0.0.Alpha7

Answer (score 0):

You are missing @Entity annotation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Person {
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Entity` is a way to let hibernate know its a table.
you can read more here:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-entity

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved just by importing javax.persistence.Id in Person.java
and then adding the @Id annotation before the declaration of id variable.